# How to avoid printing un-necessary information while running python from shell?

Tags: python, shell, machine-learning

I am running a neural network program from shell. It is running right but it prints all the information besides my output which I really don't need. The detail is given in the picture attached. [image]

I haven't written anything in my code to print this un-necessary information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might have `log_device_placement` turned on. You can turn this off by either removing it from the config in `tf.Session()` entirely or setting it to `False`.

```
# Example 1
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False))

# Example 2
sess = tf.Session()
```

References:

- [Tensorflow - Using GPUs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu)